# how to achieve image slider in android application?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to have a login view similar to foursquare, can any one tell me how can i achieve this ? i have this youtube video for reference. http://youtu.be/RmQH0s2f2D8

Comment: Use viewpagers. Its quite simple. Google about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) to achieve that.

Here are a few tutorials on it if the one above doesn't suffice.

[Android User Interface Design: Horizontal View Paging](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging--mobile-8231)

[Android (support v4) ViewPager tutorial (including source code)](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/android-support-v4-viewpager-tutorial-including-source-code/)

[Working with Fragments and ViewPager on Android](http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2013/10/20/working-with-fragments-and-viewpager-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a `ViewPager`

The [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) are pretty good in this case, so that should help.

As far as the popup at the bottom of the screen, you can hook it in to a [page change listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) and animate it up/down depending on the page.